# ui:inputSelect required="true" not working on a Lightning Component

Tags: lightning

I am not able to make ui:inputSelect, as required by adding an attribute, required="true"
Below is the code, after adding the required="true" also, I was able to save the Lightning component without any error

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
   <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="label">Label</label>
   <div class="slds-form-element__control">
       <div class="slds-select_container">
          <ui:inputSelect aura:id="picklist"
                                class="slds-select" 
                                value="{!v.Picklist__c}" required="true">
                    <ui:inputSelectOption label="--None--" text=""/>
                    <ui:inputSelectOption label="Yes" text="Yes"/>
                    <ui:inputSelectOption label="No" text="No"/>
                </ui:inputSelect>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Any solutions to make required="true" to work
Thanks
```

Comment: Hi, you promise code below, have you forgotten to ad the code?

Comment: @FlorianHeer Added code

Comment: since you have not shared your full code,whatever function you are calling when you save just check if select  value is what you want or not and throw error according to that

Answer (score 1):

You should use lightning:select or lightning:combobox instead because ui:inputSelect is deprecated as of API version 47.0.

Reference -https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/example

With lightning:select you can use required="true"

```
<lightning:select name="select1" label="How many tickets?" required="true">
    <option value="">choose one...</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</lightning:select>
```

Comment: I am updating in an existing component which is in production, I cannot update the ui:inputselect to lightning:select, any changes to make it required in ui:inputselect

Comment: I don't know the reason but if you add label="something" in ui:inputSelect, asterisk will appear otherwise not. Apart from UI, you will validate the required functionality in js while saving.